# Deploy and changing URL for a node js and Laravel Site

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I have an app in laravel that runs on a remote server (digital ocean) and I've created a snapshot from my server and than created another droplet from the snapshot. Changed Ngnix conf files to add an stage before the url address and updated .env files.

I can run api and manager for my app, but And the www site always returns /500 url address. Is there a step-by-step guide for cloning my server and change my URL?

---Editing -----
The error show at browser is:

```
homologacao.mysite.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

This is my ngnix conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80;   

    server_name www.homologacao.mysite.com www.homologacao.mysite.com.br homologacao.mysite.com.br homologacao.mysite.com default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location ~/.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 250m;

    access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/nginx.www.access.log;
    error_log  /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/nginx.www.error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5003;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

# API
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/api/current/public;

    client_max_body_size 250m;

    server_name apihml.mysite.com;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/api.nginx.access.log;
    error_log /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/api.nginx.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    charset utf-8;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass deployer-php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}

# MANAGER
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name managerhml.mysite.com;
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/manager/public;


    access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/manager.nginx.access.log;
    error_log /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/logs/manager.nginx.error.log;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    location ~/.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant config, esp. on the nginx part.

Comment: check the laravel logs in 'storage/logs/laravel.log' for the specfic error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.